# Retrieve Reference and Display Images

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I followed the provided answer in this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071883/sqlite-retrieving-image-by-path) and It basically shows me how to store a reference to an image in my database after it is captured using the camera.

How can I display the image based on that reference? I'm using a GridView and a custom adapter to display these images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_path);
img .setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

where img_path is the path stored in your database

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can see this working. But I have one problem, I have multiple reference paths stored in the Database and I want to iterate through them and display them all in the gridview. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: get all of your image paths from database and store in a `ArrayList<String>` and use them in gridview according to your need

Comment: I accepted your answer because it worked! Thanks a lot, I've been looking for this answer for a while.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you, check the `readFromDB()` method

[STORE AND READ IMAGES](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/)

the method taken from the link (i suggest you read the whole post)

```
 void readFromDB() {
        byte[] byteImage2 = null;
        SQLiteDatabase myDb;
        myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor cur = myDb.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            textView.append("\n Reading Details \n Name : " + cur.getString(1));
            cur.moveToNext();
        }

        // /////Read data from blob field////////////////////
        cur.moveToFirst();
        byteImage2 = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("image"));
        setImage(byteImage2);
        cur.close();
        myDb.close();
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),
                "Image read from DB successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),
                "If your image is big, please scrolldown to see the result.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    void setImage(byte[] byteImage2) {
        image2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage2, 0,
                byteImage2.length));
        textView.append("\n Image Size : " + byteImage2.length + " KB");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However that link shows you how to achieve the solution by storing and retrieving the image as a BLOB. I am not storing the actual image in the database, just a reference to it (e.g image name or path).

Comment: oh im sorry. Having path is waaay easier. What Kunu answered is fine. Good luck